# Disable Navigation UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have an app with UIPageViewController implementation, with 14 ViewControllers, and I need to disable the navigation until animation finish, but by default, I can touch or swipe to change view...

Edit:

PageViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
var contentPageRestorationIDs = [String]()
var pageViewController = UIPageViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    contentPageRestorationIDs = ["FirstView", "SecondView", "ThirdView", "FourthView", "FiveView", "SixView", "SevenView", "EightView", "NineView", "TenView", "ElevenView", "TwelveView", "ThirteenView", "FourteenView"]
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as UIPageViewController
    pageViewController.dataSource = self

    var startingController: UIViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)!

    pageViewController.setViewControllers([startingController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


}

func goToPreviousContentViewController(){

    var currentViewController: AnyObject = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0]
    var vcRestorationID = currentViewController.restorationIdentifier
    var index = find(contentPageRestorationIDs, vcRestorationID!!)

    var previousViewController: UIViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index! - 1)!

    pageViewController.setViewControllers([previousViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Reverse, animated: false, completion: nil)



}

func goToNextContentViewController(){

    var currentViewController: AnyObject = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0]
    var vcRestorationID = currentViewController.restorationIdentifier
    var index = find(contentPageRestorationIDs, vcRestorationID!!)

    var nextViewController: BaseContentViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index! - 1)!

    pageViewController.setViewControllers([nextViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> (UIViewController?){
    var vcRestorationID = viewController.restorationIdentifier
    var index = find(contentPageRestorationIDs, vcRestorationID!)

    if(index == 0){
        return nil
    }
    return viewControllerAtIndex(index! - 1)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> (UIViewController?){
    var vcRestorationID = viewController.restorationIdentifier
    var index = find(contentPageRestorationIDs, vcRestorationID!)

    if(index == contentPageRestorationIDs.count - 1){
        return nil
    }
    return viewControllerAtIndex(index! + 1)


}


func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> (Int){
    return self.contentPageRestorationIDs.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> (Int){
    return 0
}


func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int)-> (BaseContentViewController!) {

    if(index >= contentPageRestorationIDs.count){
        return nil
    }

    var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))

    var contentViewController: BaseContentViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(self.contentPageRestorationIDs[index]) as BaseContentViewController

    contentViewController.rootViewController = self

    contentViewController.loadView()

    return contentViewController

}
}
```

BaseContentViewController.swift (All my ViewControllers extends from this)

```
import UIKit

class BaseContentViewController: UIViewController {

var rootViewController: PageViewController = PageViewController()
var goNext = Bool()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

Comment: Try setting the page view controller `dataSource` to nil, until the animation has completed, and then set it again once you are happy for navigation to continue.  From the docs: "Methods of the data source are called in response to gesture-based navigation. If the value of this property is nil, then gesture-based navigation is disabled."

Comment: Thanks, but, how can I change the dataSource from the ViewController???

Comment: I think I would implement a protocol/delegate call-back from the ViewController to the page view controller.  In the View Controller, define a protocol with methods like "enableNavigation" and "disableNavigation", and a delegate property which adopts this protocol.  In the PVC, set the delegate property to `self` when creating the ViewControllers, and implement those two methods to set/clear the dataSource.

Comment: Ok, thanks!!i I try and tell you something!!!

Comment: Ok, I try but it not work... One thing more complex is what I need. I can go back in any moment, but only to the next view when the animations finished. I update with code of the Page View Controller and the RootViewController

Comment: To enable "swipe to go back" but disable "swipe to go forward" you would need to keep the dataSource set, and return nil from `viewControllerAfterViewController`.  However, the page view controller caches this information, so you would _never_ be able to swipe forward.  I think you might have to abandon gesture based navigation altogether, and rely on buttons for "go forward" and "go back".

Comment: Ok, and how can I apply the navigation go forward and go back only in a Button? Because now I have a button to move between views, but if I touch left frame or right frame it moves back and forward...

Comment: If you set the pageViewController's `dataSource` to nil, it will disable gesture based navigation, but you will lose the page control functionality (eg. `presentationCountForPageViewController:`).  If that is a problem, then keep the `dataSource` but amend the `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController` methods to return nil in all cases.

Comment: The principal reason why I implement the PageViewController is for mantain the Page Curl Transition Effect. If I make any of 2 thinks that you recomend me, I lose this effect. In my views I have a button that only enables when the animation ends, and this button call to the self.performSegueWithIdentifier("viewID", sender: nil)

Comment: Sorry if I am just confusing the situation.  Things work slightly differently for the Page Curl transition, in that the page view controller does not cache the results of `viewControllerAfterViewController`.  So, I think you can achieve what you wish by 1) keep the dataSource set to self, 2) amend `viewControllerAfterViewController` to test whether the video is still playing, and if so return `nil`.

Comment: From today, you are my HERO!!!! Thanks, in 2 hours I update with the solution!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try on the following option per your requirement

Recommended

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Or Simply Disable by on Edge case

```
self.view.window.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Update: Recently Apple doesn't allow the back button to enable / disable. Instead of that we can hide it.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, I don't use the navigation buttons for navigate. If I disable the user interaction, I crash de functionality of my app

Answer (score 0):

In general, it would be best not to prevent user from using the UI and perhaps terminate the animation, instead.

Apparently this is not possible in your use case. You could create  flag in the application that indicates if it is ok to show the next controller and create logic in viewControllerAfterViewController to prevent showing the next controller.

Comment: Ok, is very simple, the app is a story for the children, like a Book, but is interactive, after each animation, the character ask a question and, if the answer is correct, I allow to go forward. I use UIPageViewController because I need Page Curl effect, and is the only/best way to apply this effect.

Comment: Yes, I see it. Is not possible to have a Book effect but disabling the interaction with the left and right edges until a time?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that i got your question right just use

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
```

then after the animation end show it again

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false
```

Comment: I have the navigation bar hidden in all the app